# Should number of votes and/or higher answers be listed higher?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, votes

Unless Im mistaken, answers to questions appear in reverse chronological order, with newer answers being first in the list.

Ive always felt that the accepted answer should be listed first and then descending by the highest number of votes.  Isnt the purpose to find *the* answer, or best possible answers?

If I was a new person Googling a problem and came across this site, as it had my question, I wouldnt want to sift through a variety of answers, which can range from wrong to poor.  I would expect the best answers at the top.

Just my opinion.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above the answer list, there's three tabs: *active* (descending by change), *oldest* (ascending by age), and *votes*, the last one being the default when you haven't changed the order.

In all of these sort modes, the accepted answer is first *only if not by the same user as the question*.

So your request is actually the default, and (AFAIK) has been from the beginning. Open a private browsing tab to get rid of your cookies and [see for yourself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SHV9.png).

Comment: you know, I never noticed that :D

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that IS how they're ordered.  Accepted first, then highest vote count and descending, with some randomization for equal-voted answers (to prevent me-too type voting).

If I'm wrong, please correct me.

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)  Seems to be a fair proof of case.

Comment: There is one exception. If you self-answer and accept your own answer, that answer is not raised to the top of the list. Instead, it remains in the vote sort order.